# Extend the fiber of a principal $PSU(n)$-bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, principal-bundles

For $n>2$, the outer automorphism group of $PSU(n)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

My question: Given a principal $PSU(n)$-bundle $P$ over a manifold $M$, can we extend the fiber of $P$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2\ltimes PSU(n)$? That is, can we find a principal $\mathbb{Z}_2\ltimes PSU(n)$ bundle over $M$? Here the semidirect product is given by the outer automorphism.

The case $n=2$ is also interesting, in this case, the question is: Given a principal $SO(3)$-bundle over a manifold $M$, can we find a principal $O(3)$-bundle over $M$?

For $n>2$, let $H=PSU(n)$, $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\ltimes PSU(n)$; For $n=2$, let $H=SO(3)$, $G=O(3)$.

Following Mike Miller's comment, we can construct a principal $G$-bundle $P\times_H G$ over $M$ from the principal $H$-bundle $P$ over $M$.

What is the relation between the Stiefel-Whitney classes of the associated vector bundles of $P\times_H G$ and $P$?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes? There is an injection to your group from $PSU(n)$. In general if $H \to G$ is a closed subgroup and $P$ is a principal $H$-bundle, $P \times_H G$ is a principal $G$-bundle.